# Namespace issue

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

> I have a input xml where S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" this giving a problem to fetching data from faultsting node..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The GTIN is not valid or the system can not map the Company Prefix to an existing Company Prefix from the Setting</faultstring>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

> Xlst code is not working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="example" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
exclude-result-prefixes="S ns4">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/S:Envelope">
            <ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB xmlns:ns0="example">
            <serialNumberList xmlns="urn:abcd:1">
                <body>
                    <message>
                        <xsl:value-of select="S:Body/ns4:Fault/ns4:faultstring"/>
                    </message>
                </body>
            </serialNumberList>
        </ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> **Expected result...Please help find the code error if i missed something**

```
<ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB xmlns:ns0="example">
    <serialNumberList xmlns="urn:abcd:1">
        <body><message>The GTIN is not valid or the system can not map the Company Prefix to an existing Company Prefix from the Setting</message>
        </body>
    </serialNumberList>
</ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="example" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
exclude-result-prefixes="S ns4">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/S:Envelope">
            <ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB xmlns:ns0="example">
            <serialNumberList xmlns="urn:abcd:1">
                <body>
                    <message>
                        <xsl:value-of select="S:Body/S:Fault/faultstring"/>
                    </message>
                </body>
            </serialNumberList>
        </ns0:MT_CreateSerialNumberResponse_IB>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no node in the input XML whose name is prefixed by `ns4:`. That makes the namespace declaration `xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"` entirely redundant (in both XML and XSLT).
2. Only *default* namespace declarations (without a prefix) are inherited. The `faultstring` element has no prefix and no default namespace declaration in scope. That means it is in no-namespace, and the path to it (from the context of `S:Envelope`) is:

   `S:Body/S:Fault/faultstring`